# I'm getting watchdog timer resets in NodeMCU. How can I permanently disable or stop that?

Tags: wifi, nodemcu, watchdog

I'm using NodeMCU for my project. At first it works fine, but after some days it is resetting frequently because of the watchdog timer. I have used the `Esp.wdtfeed()` method also. But it is not working. Can you please tell me what the problem exactly with or any solution? Here is my code:

```cpp
void setup(void) {
  ESP.wdtDisable();
  ESP.wdtEnable(WDTO_8S);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();
  Serial.println("");
  if (n == 0)
    Serial.println("no networks found");
  else {
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
      if(WiFi.SSID(i)==ssid1) {
        WiFi.begin(ssid1,password1);
        ssid=ssid1;
      } else if(WiFi.SSID(i)==ssid2) {
        WiFi.begin(ssid2,password2);
        ssid=ssid2;
      } else if(WiFi.SSID(i)==ssid3) {
        WiFi.begin(ssid3,password3);
        ssid=ssid3;
      }
    }
  }
  display.init();
  display.flipScreenVertically();
  display.setFont(ArialMT_Plain_16);
  display.setTextAlignment(TEXT_ALIGN_LEFT);
  display.drawStringMaxWidth(15,15, 128,"Display started");
  display.display();
  // Wait for connection
  display.clear();  
  int j=0;
  while(j<10) {
    display.drawStringMaxWidth(15,15, 128,"connected to");
    display.drawStringMaxWidth(15,32, 128,ssid);
    display.display();
    display.clear();
    delay(1000);
    j++;
  }
  display.drawStringMaxWidth(15,32, 128,"");
  display.display();
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  display.clear();
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  if (mdns.begin("esp8266WebForm", WiFi.localIP())) {
    Serial.println("MDNS responder started");
  }
  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);
  server.begin();
  Serial.print("Connect to http://esp8266WebForm.local or http://");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  server.on("/", getvalues);
  pinMode(buzzPin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(but,INPUT);
}

void loop(void) {
  ESP.wdtFeed();
  if((WiFi.status()== WL_DISCONNECTED)||(WiFi.status()==WL_CONNECTION_LOST)) { 
    display.drawStringMaxWidth(15,15, 128,"disconnected");
    display.display();
    int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();
    Serial.println("");
    if (n == 0)
      Serial.println("no networks found");
    else {
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        if(WiFi.SSID(i)==ssid1) {
          WiFi.begin(ssid1,password1);
          ssid=ssid1;
        } else if(WiFi.SSID(i)==ssid2) {
          WiFi.begin(ssid2,password2);
          ssid=ssid2;
        } else if(WiFi.SSID(i)==ssid3) {
          WiFi.begin(ssid3,password3);
          ssid=ssid3;
        }
      }
      int j=0;
      display.clear();
      while(j<10) {
        display.drawStringMaxWidth(15,15, 128,"connected to");
        display.drawStringMaxWidth(15,32, 128,ssid);
        display.display();
        display.clear();
        delay(1000);
        j++;
      }
      display.clear();
      display.drawStringMaxWidth(15,32, 128,"");
      display.display();
    }
  }
  getvalues();
  delay(20000);
}
```

Comment: Likely, you will get some humerus comments (like do you work for a certain car company).  Seriously, it sounds like the watch dog has found a problem with your code or hardware.  Rather than defeating the watch dog, most people here will suggest you find the cause (why your code has failed to "kick the dog").

Comment: Could you post the error output from the console?

Answer (score 2):

here my way to find the bug first
1.comment out the watchdog from the code.
2.debug the code flow and find it get struck. Debugging in the sense put "Serial.print()" in between your code where you feel stuck but here don't disable your watchdog.

Answer (score 1):

After long time I have seen this question and thought of answering as I found the issue at that time itself, But not posted here.

After debugging for long time, I got to know that there is a string i am initializing with the data fetched from a site which has been overflown beyond the memory of NodeMCU. due to which it has thrown watchdog exception, So please do memory management properly as NodeMCU cannot do data processing and all.